# Starting systemd .service at boot, eth0 not found

Tags: service, embedded-linux, ethernet, systemd, systemctl

I am using systemd to start an executable at boot time on a single board computer (embedded) platform. I want this app to run in headless mode - no logging in - and the user will control the input through a web browser.

I am using a TS-7800-V2 which runs Debian.

Here is my service (webserver.service) set up (etc/systemd/system):

```
[Unit]
Description=Run LWSWS webserver on startup
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/libwebsockets/build/bin/lwsws

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have enabled and started the service, and checked the status:

```
root@ts7800-v2:~# systemctl status webserver.service 
��● webserver.service - Run LWSWS webserver on startup
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webserver.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-12-11 11:23:39 PST; 11min ago
 Main PID: 2408 (lwsws)
   CGroup: /system.slice/webserver.service
       ��└��─2408 /libwebsockets/build/bin/lwsws

Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]:    mounting callback://proto
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]:  Using non-SSL mode
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]: created client ssl context f
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]: Unable to find interface eth
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]: init server failed
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]: Failed to create vhost local
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]: /etc/lwsws/conf.d/test-serve
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: lwsws[2416]: Context creation failed
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: GPS THREAD created successfully
Dec 11 11:23:39 ts7800-v2 lwsws[2408]: MOTOR CONTROL THREAD created successfully
```

So, the service is active and running, but the eth0 connection is not being made so that the web server (libwebsockets web server LWSWS) cannot start up properly.

**My question is how to get Ethernet to startup on boot so that the web server can start up and run?**

In the dependencies for this service, the networking shows in the tree before the rest of the service startup:

```
root@ts7800-v2:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl list-dependencies webserver.service
��● ��├��─system.slice
��● ��├��─network-online.target
��● ��│ ��└��─networking.service
��● ��└��─sysinit.target
��●   ��├��─dev-hugepages.mount
��●   ��├��─dev-mqueue.mount
��●   ��├��─kmod-static-nodes.service
��●   ��├��─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
��●   ��├��─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
��●   ��├��─sys-kernel-config.mount
��●   ��├��─sys-kernel-debug.mount
��●   ��├��─systemd-ask-password-console.path
��●   ��├��─systemd-binfmt.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-hwdb-update.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-journal-flush.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-journald.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-machine-id-commit.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-modules-load.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-random-seed.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-sysctl.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-timesyncd.service
��●   ��├��─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
```

Advice on how to get the network started before the web server starts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/502793/how-to-bring-network-up-at-boot-time-in-linux/503086#503086

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing managing of a network interface. Something like `NetworkManager`. If you are already using systemd maybe `systemd-networkd` is a solution for you. Please read [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd) from ArchLinux Wiki for reference.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I posted my own answer to address the issue exactly. This answer definitely gets to the root of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to get the ethernet connection to auto-start when the app is in headless mode. Here is the contents (cat) of the etc/network/interfaces file:

```
root@ts7800-v2:/etc/network# cat interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I added the line "auto eth0" and now ethernet is started up before my webserver.service is called.